# No function clause matching in Regex.match?/2 on Elixir w/ Phoenix

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a route in Phoenix that needs to check the JSON parameters with REGEX.
In my routine, I am creating a list of errors to report in the body in case one or more regexes fail. 
But whenever I run the code, I get the "FunctionClauseError" error on "Regex.match?". I have tried String.match, but they evaluate to the same function.

Here is my code:

```
   def postServidor(conn, parameters) do
        reasons = []
        error = False
        if not Regex.match?(~r/^(19[0-9]{2}|2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[012])-([123]0|[012][1-9]|31)$/, Map.get(parameters, "data_nascimento")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[data_nascimento] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should look like this: 1969-02-12"}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?(~r/^([A-Z][a-z]+([ ]?[a-z]?['-]?[A-Z][a-z]+)*)$/, Map.get(parameters, "nome")) do            
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[name] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should look like this: Firstname Middlename(optional) Lastname"}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?(~r/^([A-Z][a-z]+([ ]?[a-z]?['-]?[A-Z][a-z]+)*)$/, Map.get(parameters, "nome_identificacao")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[nome_identificacao] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should look like this: Firstname Middlename(optional) Lastname"}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?(~r/\b[MF]{1}\b/, Map.get(parameters, "sexo")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[sexo] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should look like this: M for male, F for female"}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?( ~r/\b[0-9]+\b/, Map.get(parameters, "id_pessoa")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[id_pessoa] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should be numeric. "}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?(~r/\b[0-9]+\b/, Map.get(parameters, "matricula_interna")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[matricula_interna] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should be numeric. "}]}
        end
        if not Regex.match?(~r/\b[0-9]+\b/, Map.get(parameters, "siape")) do
            {error, reasons} = {True, reasons ++ [%{Reason => "[siape] missing or failed to match API requirements. It should be numeric. "}]}
        end
        if error = True do
            json put_status(conn, 400),reasons
        else
            IO.puts("ok")
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.match?/2` requires a string as its second argument. You're using `Map.get/3` to potentially return that string, but if the key isn't found in the map, it defaults to `nil`, and that's my guess as to what's happening. If the key is not found in your map, it's passing `nil` to `Regex.match?/2`, for which there will be no function clause that matches. You can either fix your map to correctly have the key, or you can provide your own default string to use as a third parameter to `Map.get/3`. For example, `Map.get(parameters, "data_nascimento", "some default")`.

Comment: Some of my Map values were integers, this was causing the problem. I have also implemented your "dafault" failsafe. Thanks !

Comment: Glad it was helpful!